# Why can't we locate the exact number of rows?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, less, craco

craco.config.js

```
const CracoLessPlugin = require("craco-less");

module.exports = {
  plugins:[
    {
      plugin: CracoLessPlugin,
    }
  ]
};
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHbxT.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAflm.jpg)

Why can't we locate the exact number of rows?

Accurate line number

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.